# Error setting up Drive API with Python from Jupyter

Tags: python, google-api, google-drive-api, jupyter

I'm following the [Google Quickstart Guide](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/quickstart/python) to set-up Python to access the Google Drive API from a Jupyter notebook (with the ultimate goal of adding a csv to a specific Google Drive folder).

After following steps 1) and 2), I'm adding the quickstart code.

quickstart.py

```
"""
Shows basic usage of the Drive v3 API.

Creates a Drive v3 API service and prints the names and ids of the last 10 files
the user has access to.
"""
from __future__ import print_function
from apiclient.discovery import build
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

# Setup the Drive v3 API
SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.metadata.readonly'
store = file.Storage('credentials.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
service = build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

# Call the Drive v3 API
results = service.files().list(
    pageSize=10, fields="nextPageToken, files(id, name)").execute()
items = results.get('files', [])
if not items:
    print('No files found.')
else:
    print('Files:')
    for item in items:
        print('{0} ({1})'.format(item['name'], item['id']))
```

Running that, I'm getting the following error:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                             [--noauth_local_webserver]
                             [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                             [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /Users/miguel/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-dc5eae05-373c-42a9-a2da-86c096ca8330.json
```

I've googled and found some stuff here (including [this](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/transcript/143133/2017/5/2/0-2) chat which seems like a similar issue) but I can't fix the problem. After commenting out parts of the code, it seems like the line throwing the error is

```
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

Any idea how to solve this?

**EDIT:**

I managed to find a [better Google tutorial](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/gsuite-apis-intro/#6) to follow. Following all the steps there, **I can get the script to work as a standalone python script.** However, it still doesn't work when run from a Jupyter notebook.

The code used is similar to the previous one.

```
from __future__ import print_function

from apiclient import discovery
from httplib2 import Http
from oauth2client import file, client, tools

SCOPES = 'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive.readonly.metadata'
store = file.Storage('storage.json')
creds = store.get()
if not creds or creds.invalid:
    flow = client.flow_from_clientsecrets('client_secret.json', SCOPES)
    creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
DRIVE = discovery.build('drive', 'v3', http=creds.authorize(Http()))

files = DRIVE.files().list().execute().get('files', [])
for f in files:
    print(f['name'], f['mimeType'])
```

The line throwing the error is the same:

```
creds = tools.run_flow(flow, store)
```

And the error returned is the same:

```
usage: ipykernel_launcher.py [--auth_host_name AUTH_HOST_NAME]
                             [--noauth_local_webserver]
                             [--auth_host_port [AUTH_HOST_PORT [AUTH_HOST_PORT ...]]]
                             [--logging_level {DEBUG,INFO,WARNING,ERROR,CRITICAL}]
ipykernel_launcher.py: error: unrecognized arguments: -f /Users/miguel/Library/Jupyter/runtime/kernel-a0ff6ecb-3947-41be-be03-d2d96776fc8e.json
```

For clarity: the main thing from this edit is that the code works from a standalone script but not when run in a Jupyter notebook.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Google-oauth inside Jupyter Notebook](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41961949/google-oauth-inside-jupyter-notebook)

Comment: Did you ever find a solution to this?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using google colab with and adding a drive are these 3 Cells:

Cell  1:

```
!apt-get install -y -qq software-properties-common python-software-properties module-init-tools
!add-apt-repository -y ppa:alessandro-strada/ppa 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get update -qq 2>&1 > /dev/null
!apt-get -y install -qq google-drive-ocamlfuse fuse

from google.colab import authi
auth.authenticate_user()
from oauth2client.client import GoogleCredentials
creds = GoogleCredentials.get_application_default()
import getpass

!google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret} < /dev/null 2>&1 | grep URL
vcode = getpass.getpass()
!echo {vcode} | google-drive-ocamlfuse -headless -id={creds.client_id} -secret={creds.client_secret}
```

Cell  2:

```
!mkdir -p drive
!google-drive-ocamlfuse drive
```

Cell 3 (output drive folder):

```
!ls drive
```

To access the drive use:

```
path = 'drive/somedrivefolder'
```